# Initializing a List into a static method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 6 operators that i am trying to push into a operator class. I need to initialise the list of the new operators so they can be used effectively. I've got myself in quite a mess and am having a fair few syntax problems, any help would be greatly appreciated in creating the list.

```
public static List<ComparisonOperator> CreateComparisonOperators()      
    {
        this.Condition1Select.Items.Clear();
        this.Condition2Select.Items.Clear();
        this.Condition3Select.Items.Clear();
        this.Condition4Select.Items.Clear();


        foreach (ComparisonOperator op in ops)
        {
            this.Condition1Select.Items.Add(op);
            this.Condition2Select.Items.Add(op);
            this.Condition3Select.Items.Add(op);
            this.Condition4Select.Items.Add(op);
        }



       return new List<ComparisonOperator>();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use the `this` keyword in a static method. So basically you can forget about accessing your controls in a static method.

Comment: Can you make your lists static?

Comment: well thank you, saves me a lot of wasted time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this`statement means that you refer to the current instance. For static methods you don't have any instance and for this can't use the `this`statement. You would need to make the `List`static, too. Also the ComparisonOperator enumeration `ops`needs to be static.